# $yesterday = $today.setDate($today.getDate() - 1); not displaying yesterday's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to fetch yesterday's date in my startdate field and today's date in my endate field. However, this is not working. Everytime it is displaying today's date. I searched on stackflow for different solutions but this is not working.Can someone please help me with this.

```js
$today = new Date();
$yesterday = $today.setDate($today.getDate() - 1);

$('.panel-body').find('#startdate').datepicker('setDate', $yesterday );
$('.panel-body').find('#enddate').datepicker('setDate', $today);
```

Comment: can you post a working snippent?

Comment: Consider `$('#startdate')` instead of `$('.panel-body').find('#startdate')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a setDate to `$today` it changes the Date of the `$today` variable. And when you assign the value to `$yesterday`, it assigns the `$today.getTime()` value.

Refer the following code for solution:

```js
var $today = new Date();
var $yesterday = new Date($today);
$yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 1);
console.log('Today', $today);
console.log('Yesterday', $yesterday);
```

Comment: Possibly better to use `$yesterday = new Date($today)`, then change *$yesterday*'s date as it would match the OP's case better, but +1 anyway. ;-)

Comment: @RobG thanks for the suggestion. Updated the answer.